# An access database vba UPDATE SQL command has stopped working after Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 Version 4.8.03761 installation today

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

An access database vba `UPDATE SQL` command has stopped working after **Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 Version 4.8.03761 installation** today.

Users encounter the message:

```
"Run-time error '3340': Query " is corrupt.
```

The code that now fails is:

```
Public Function UpdateMachine()

Dim TEST_SQL_command As String

TEST_SQL_command = "UPDATE [People] " & SET [Machine] = '" & ComputerUsed & "' WHERE [Personid] = " & UserPersonID & ";"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (TEST_SQL_Command)
DoCmd.SetWarning True

DoCmd.Save

End Function
```

Comment: `"UPDATE [People] " & SET [Machine] = '"` this doesn't look right, should it be `"UPDATE [People] SET [Machine] = '"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your SQL String could cause the issue. You have SET and WHERE out of the string

```
TEST_SQL_command = "UPDATE [People] SET [Machine] = '" & ComputerUsed & "' WHERE [Personid] = " & UserPersonID & ";"
```

Comment: That's not the issue. See the duplicate, this is a highly specific issue introduced by a Windows Update.